# Big query data storage cost

Tags: google-bigquery

If the data is stored in Google's BigQuery, I can see how much I get charged on a monthly basis in [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/). Say if I save up 1 TB of data every month and if I leave the data for 2 years then will have 24 TB of stored data. Will that mean I'll be paying for 24TB worth of storage? I guess so - but the calculator doesn't make it very clear. Could some one please confirm this from Google's BigQuery team?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't directly about programming. (Consider contacting Google)

Comment: Please do - https://cloud.google.com/support/ according to that page I could only use stackoverflow, the bigquery-discuss group is closed. I think Google needs a better place to ask these questions and if someone knows of that place please share it and I'll be happy to use that instead of SO.

Comment: You pay monthly, so if you have 24TB in that month stored, you need to pay it. You can delete old tables in case you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is off-topic, but in any case :

you pay for everything stored, so if you store 1 TB a month, you will end up paying 24TB in 2 years indeed.

You can (and maybe should) use an "[expiration time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource)" when you create your table, this way your tables clear automatically when enough time has elapsed.

You could also have a cron job on App Engine that runs over your TB of data and "compresses it" (I guess after a month, you don't need every single row of data, but rather statistics on it, which you could create before deleting the table with the data).

Also consider doing backups of your data, compressing them, then storing them on Google Cloud Storage, and restoring them as needed (indeed, you pay for TB/months. So if you load 24 TBs for one day, you don't even pay a full TB month). Do note there are fees with storing in GCS though, so you'd have to study the full usage to make sure this will be worth it.